# how many times a word is repeated using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in project in VBA, and I want to know what is the most reviewed product from a data set 
I have tried the following :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long, Ligne As Long
    Dim BCP As Workbook
    Dim fd As FileDialog, CheminBCP$



    dossierMacro = Left(ThisWorkbook.FullName, InStr(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ThisWorkbook.Name) - 1)

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        .Title = "Choisir Base de données   "
        .InitialFileName = dossierMacro
        If .Show = -1 Then
            CheminBCP = fd.SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    Set fd = Nothing
    Set BCP = Workbooks.Open(CheminBCP)

    Ligne = BCP.Sheets(1).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To Ligne
    a = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("A" & i))
    Next
    MsgBox a
    b = WorksheetFunction.Max(a)
    MsgBox b
    End Sub
```

I have tried this code:

First of all: I choose my file which I want to work on

Second: the variable Ligne indicates the number of the last line

Then: I make for to count the number of repetition

then: I make the variable b the maximum of a to the most reviewed

But the  problem for both variables a and b I get 0 .

I don't if the problem was in my Count function

Hope anyone could help me, Thanks

Comment: How does the worksheet look like? Please post a screenshot (or at least a link to).

Comment: that's right i will try to upload it to the drive and link it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that `Ligne` is equal to `10`, your code:

```
For i = 2 To Ligne
    a = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("A" & i))
Next
MsgBox a
b = WorksheetFunction.Max(a)
MsgBox b
```

... would do this:

- From `2` to `10`, it redefines the variable `a` with the `.Count` of `Range("A2")`, `Range("A3")`, ... `Range("A10")`. The function `Count` (check [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.count)) counts the number of cells containing numerical values in a range. For example, if you say `.Count(Range("A2:A4")` and you have `A2="b"`, `A3=4` and `A4="c3"`, you would get `1` (the cell `A2`). Since your loop always redefines `a`, when you exit the loop `a` is the number of numeric cells inside the range `Range("A10")` (i.e. `Range("A" & Ligne)`. It can be `1` or `0`, in your case is `0` apparently.
- Then, you just try to get the `.Max()` of the number `a`. Since `a` is `0`, `b` is necessarily going to be `0` as well (more generally, for how you wrote the code, `b` is always going to be equal to `a`).

Without a data sample, we can't help you much. But if I assume that you have a list of data like this:

```
COLUMN A
--------
PRODUCT
Apple
Android
Android
Android
Apple
Windows
Apple
Android
```

.. then you could design your loop like this:

```
Set Products = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") '<-- list of products and count of occurrencies
For i = 2 To Ligne
    If Not Products.Exists(Range("A" & i).Value) Then
        'first time we count this product.
        'we add it to the dictionary with count 1
        Products.Add Range("A" & i).Value, 1
    Else
        'not first time we count this product
        'we increase its count by 1
        currentCount = Products(Range("A" & i).Value)
        currentCount = currentCount + 1
        Products(Range("A" & i).Value) = currentCount
    End If
Next i

'define mock variable for highest count
highestCount = -1
'loop through each product and get the one with highest count
For Each Product In Products.Keys
    If Products(Product) > highestCount Then
        highestCount = Products(Product)
        mostReviewedProduct = Product
    End If
Next Product
```

With the above code and the sample data I posted, you would get `highestCount` = 4 and `mostReviewedProduct` = Android.

Answer (score 0):

Though @Matteo NNZ nicely explained where code is going wrong (pl go through the explanation) . Another Approach inline with your code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long, Ligne As Long
    Dim BCP As Workbook
    Dim fd As FileDialog, CheminBCP$
    Dim Rng As Range, Mx As Long, Cnt As Long
    Dim ProductX As String, ProductY As String

    dossierMacro = Left(ThisWorkbook.FullName, InStr(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ThisWorkbook.Name) - 1)
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        .Title = "Choisir Base de données   "
        .InitialFileName = dossierMacro
        If .Show = -1 Then
            CheminBCP = fd.SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    Set fd = Nothing
    Set BCP = Workbooks.Open(CheminBCP)

    Ligne = BCP.Sheets(1).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Mx = 0
    ProductY = ""

    For i = 2 To Ligne
    ProductX = BCP.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
        'Test if ProductX is unique i.e. not counted before
        If i > 2 Then
        Set Rng = BCP.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & i - 1).Find(What:=ProductX, LookIn:=xlValues)
        End If

        If Rng Is Nothing Then     ' only when Unique product is found
        'would work only if all the values in the Column A is String
        Cnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A" & Ligne), ProductX)
            If Cnt > Mx Then
            Mx = Cnt
            ProductY = ProductX
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox ProductY & " appeared Max " & Mx & " times in the list"

    End Sub
```